# Victory chart x axis remove bottom spacing

Tags: react-native, victory-charts, victory-native

[image: Victory Chart x axis bottom space]

How to remove bottom space in victory chart?

Note: I am not using SVG container.

Gold color is the view and pink color is actual chart area.

Expecting the x axis bottom space to be removed and the axis label to be visible